# Is there a 1031 Exchange equivalent in Ireland?

Tags: real-estate, financial-literacy, capital-gains-tax, ireland

I've recently been looking into buying real estate investments, & I've read about a 1031 Exchange in USA.

Here is a definition I've found:

> Thanks to IRC Section 1031, a properly structured 1031 exchange allows an investor to sell a property, to reinvest the proceeds in a new property and to defer all capital gain taxes. IRC Section 1031 (a)(1) states:
>
> No gain or loss shall be recognized on the exchange of real property held for productive use in a trade or business or for investment, if such real property is exchanged solely for real property of like-kind which is to be held either for productive use in a trade or business or for investment.

I found this definition [here](https://apiexchange.com/what-is-a-1031-exchange/).

Does anyone know if there is a similar investment vehicle in Republic of Ireland?

Comment: (A "1031 exchange" is not an investment vehicle, but a provision in the tax code.)

Comment: OK, so is there something similar to a 1031 exchange in Ireland

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? I’m looking to see if there’s an equivalent too!

Comment: Hi @Chris, sadly I did not :/